# Unused table columns are required to declare in Entity Framework objects class as properties?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-4

I have table called `Message` in my database, initially we are using Entity Framework for CRUD operation with the database, after sometime we are using stored procedures due to business logic purpose.

Issue is: in the `Message` table, we have a lot of columns, those are not used now... Those columns are added in `Message` object, even those references shows "0", because we are not using. Can remove those properties?

Comment: EF's computed select statement is built from the current model. If your model does not contain certain properties, the (used to) mapped to columns are not required anymore either. Remember to add a migration to drop these columns, or skip the model validation step in the context initializer.

Comment: In Project we are using EF approach is model first, If we remove any unused properties .... It will give any issue?

Comment: quite unlikely. Don't have much experience with model first, but with a migration to match the latest model to the database schema there should be no problem.